# Encrypt/decrypt binary content on device using CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, cryptojs

I am working on an Ionic app in which I need to encrypt/decrypt files on the device (ipad).

Use case is that when user marks some files (docx, pdf etc) as sensitive, they are encrypted on the device. Whenever user needs to view any of these files, they are decrypted back and shown to the user.

I am using CrytoJS to encrypt/decrypt the file and $cordovaFile to read/write the file to the device.

Below is the code which encrypts the file on the device. First unencrypted file is read from the device, then it is encrypted and saved back to the device.

```
return $cordovaFile.readAsBinaryString($rootScope.dataDirectory, 'abc.docx')
.then(function (binaryData) {
  console.log('Files read, now encrypt them '+binaryData);
  var encryptedWordArray = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(binaryData, '12345');
  return $cordovaFile.writeFile($rootScope.dataDirectory, 'abc.docx', encryptedWordArray.toString(), true)
})
```

This creates the encrypted file in the device but at this point I have no way to tell if the file was correctly generated except for the fact that it is not an empty file. In my example, the original docx file was 13KB but after encryption it is 23KB.

Now, I am taking the same file and trying to decrypt it.

```
var decrypted = null;
return $cordovaFile.readAsBinaryString($rootScope.dataDirectory, 'abc.docx')
  .then(function(encryptedBinaryData) {
    console.log('Read encrypted file as a binary string '+encryptedBinaryData);

    var decryptedWordArray = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedBinaryData, '12345');
    decrypted = decryptedWordArray.toString();
    return $cordovaFile.writeFile($rootScope.dataDirectory, 'abc.docx', decrypted, true)
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log('Decrypted file written');
  })
```

This generates a 34KB file on the device. However, when I try to open it, I get an error message stating that File is corrupt.

I think the problem could be somewhere related to dealing with multiple formats. When a file is read we get Binary content. Then CrytoJS gives a WordArray but before saving it to device it needs to be converted back to String.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you figure it out? It would be a great help to me.